# Shopware 6 sw-number-field: how to set id?

Tags: plugins, shopware6

How do i set `sw-number-field.id` in custom plugin?

By default, the [configuration of `sw-number-field.id`](https://component-library.shopware.com/components/sw-number-field) is [a design violation](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2).

This is observable at price fields on product detail page:

[image]

```
// sw-number-field.html.twig

<template #sw-field-input="{ identification, error, disabled, size, setFocusClass, removeFocusClass }">
    <!-- eslint-disable-next-line vuejs-accessibility/form-control-has-label -->
        <input
            :id="identification"
```

Where does `identification` come from, or where should to set it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `name` property which will also replace the auto-generated `id`.

```html
<sw-number-field name="foobar" />
<!-- becomes -->
<input id="foobar" name="foobar" type="text" placeholder="" autocomplete="off">
```

By default it is set in `src/app/component/form/field-base/sw-base-field/index.js`

```js
data() {
    return {
        id: utils.createId(),
    };
},

computed: {
    identification() {
        if (this.name) {
            return this.name;
        }

        return `sw-field--${this.id}`;
    },

    //...
}
```